# Keep the information is saved on jQuery Mobile app developed in dreamweaver

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, dreamweaver

I'm using jQuery Mobile (Dreamweaver) to develop a simple app.
I would like to understand how can I keep the saved values ​​of JQ Slider  and Collapsible Block everytime I open the application. I do not have to handle any particular function, it must only remember a selectable number or word.

Thanks for the help

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage) API:

```
localStorage.setItem("word", "your word goes here");
alert( "word = " + localStorage.getItem("word"));
```